# How to move a row from a table to another table if a Column's value changes in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables, Hosts, and UnusedHosts. Hosts has 17 columns, and UnusedHosts has 14 columns, where the first 12 is the same as in Hosts, and the 13th is a UserName, who moved a host to UnusedHosts, and the 14th is a date, when he did it. In Hosts there is a Column `Unused` which is `False`. I want do the following. If i change in Hosts this value to `True`, then it should automatically removed to UnusedHosts.

How can i do this? Could someone provide some example?

P.S.: My SQL knowledge is very small, i can use only very simple selects, updates, inserts, and delete commands.

Thanks!

Comment: I think Oracle Trigger will work for you. But still from a developer point of view i wouldn't advice that, as triggers are difficult to understand for any newbie, and will need documentation in code to mention such a thing is done in DB. But instead keep both the data in the same table. As having similar data in 2 tables make no point. And for performance you can put a index on the Column `Unused`. on select you can use `select * from table where Unused = 'true'`. This will be best according to my knowledge.

Comment: @Babu: Yes i thought someone would say that. But there are other reasons why i want the unused hosts to be stored in a different table. And i know that too, that i have to use a trigger, i just don't know how.

Comment: @kampi - Well you need to tag your question with RDBMS then as syntax differs.

Comment: @kampi please check this [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#BABCIBBJ). It explains trigger. Since i haven't worked with trigger i hope someone will explain logic for your case  if you need further assistance. But still it will be good idea to mention what DB you are using in your question

Comment: @Babu: I'm using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two main types of query in SQL Server - the AFTER and the INSTEAD OF. They work, much as they sound - the AFTER performs your original query, and then runs your trigger. The INSTEAD OF runs your trigger in place of the original query. You can use either in this case, though in different ways.

**AFTER:**

```
create trigger hosts_unused
on Hosts
after UPDATE
as

insert into UnusedHosts
select h.<<your_columns>>...
from Hosts h
where h.unused = 1 --Or however else you may be denoting True


delete from Hosts
where unused = 0 --Or however else you may be denoting False
GO
```

**INSTEAD OF:**

```
create trigger hosts_unused
on Hosts
instead of UPDATE
as

insert into UnusedHosts
select i.<<your_columns>>...
from inserted i
where i.unused = 1 --Or however else you may be denoting True

delete h
from inserted i inner join
    Hosts h on i.host_id = h.host_id
where i.unused = 1 --Or however else you may be denoting True

update h
set hosts_column_1 = i.hosts_column_1,
    hosts_column_2 = i.hosts_column_2,
    etc
from inserted i inner join
    Hosts h on i.host_id = h.host_id
where i.unused = 0 --Or however else you may be denoting False
GO
```

It's always important to think of performance when applying triggers. If you have a lot of updates on the `Hosts` table, but only a few of them are setting the `unused` column, then the AFTER trigger is probably going to give you better performance. The AFTER trigger also has the benefit that you can simply put in `, INSERT` after the `after UPDATE` bit, and it'll work for inserts too.

Check out [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) on the subject.